# Splitting strings separated by multiple possible characters?

Tags: python, split

> ...note that values will be delimited by one or more space or TAB characters

How can I use the split() method if there are multiple separating characters of different types, as in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by default split can handle multiple types of white space, not sure if it's enough for what you need but try it:

```
>>> s = "a \tb     c\t\t\td"
>>> s.split()
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

It certainly works for multiple spaces and tabs mixed.

Answer (score 2):

Split using regular expressions and not just one separator:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with some strings separated by different whitespace chars, and used **\s** as shown in the [Regular Expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) library specification.

**\s matches any whitespace character, this is equivalent to the set [ \t\n\r\f\v].**

you will need to import **re** as the regular expression handler:

```
import re
line = "something separated\t by \t\t\t different \t things"
workstr = re.sub('\s+','\t',line)
```

So, any whitespace or separator (`\s`) repeated one or more times (`+`) is transformed to a single tabulation (`\t`), that you can reprocess with split('\t')

```
workstr = "something`\t`separated`\t`by`\t`different`\t`things"
newline = workstr.split('\t')
newline = ['something','separated','by','different','things']
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a text substitution first then split.

e.g. replace all tabs with spaces, then split on space.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions first:

```
import re
re.sub('\s+', ' ', 'text     with    whitespace        etc').split()
['text', 'with', 'whitespace', 'etc']
```

Comment: You can also use `re.split` to do the splitting directly.

Answer (score 1):

For whitespace delimeters, `str.split()` already does what you may want. From [the Python Standard Library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split),

> str.**split**([*sep*[, *maxsplit*]])
>
> > **If *sep* is not specified or is `None`**, a different splitting algorithm is applied: **runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator**, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently, splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace with a None separator returns [].
> >
> > For example, `' 1  2   3  '.split()` returns `['1', '2', '3']`, and `'  1  2   3  '.split(None, 1)` returns `['1', '2   3  ']`.